# how to concat each row's max divided by two part in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am a new to tensorflow.

Acutually, My question is how to concat each row's max divided by two part in tensorflow?

Here's an example of what I want to do in numpy code.

```
def concat_rows(matrix,separete_ids):
    rows = []
    for (each_row,sep_id) in zip(matrix,separete_ids):
        s1 = np.max(each_row[:sep_id+1])
        s2 = np.max(each_row[sep_id:])
        rows.append([s1,s2])
    return np.array(rows)

np_x = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
print np_x
np_s = np.array([2,1,0,3])
print np_s
print concat_rows(np_x,np_s)
```

I am tring to use tf.py_func, but I don't know idea of gradient implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map_fn` to apply your max/min functions to each row

```
def process_row(args):
    """Returns max value before sep_id and max value after sep_id in row"""
    row = args[0]
    sep_id = args[1]
    return tf.stack([tf.reduce_max(row[:sep_id+1]), tf.reduce_max(row[sep_id:])])

array = tf.reshape(tf.range(20), (4, 5))
sepids = tf.constant([2,1,0,3], dtype=tf.int32)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.map_fn(process_row, (array, sepids), dtype=(tf.int32)))
```

This should print

```
array([[ 2,  4],
       [ 6,  9],
       [10, 14],
       [18, 19]], dtype=int32)
```